# Why isn't there any option in .NET Core for specifying Angular 6 version?

Tags: angular, .net-core

Why isn't there any option for specifying which version Angular should be used with .NET Core Angular template.

I have been using this command `dotnet new angular`, but this command is generating a template with an old version of Angular.

I want to create a project with Angular 6 with .NET Core web API.

Please let me know if there is option or way around for specifying Angular 6 template in .NET Core.

Comment: Upgrade it yourself? Not that difficult it's using `angular-cli`. Just replace everything in `ClientApp` with newly generated via `angular cli`. There are lots of tutorial out there explaining this process.

Comment: @penleychan would like to mention one of those tutorial links here

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates::2.0.0-rc1-final
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.